# Does dask_dataframe.compute() needs to be executed

Tags: python-3.x, dask

I am working on a time series analysis.
I have a dask dataframe of ~600M rows. I am creating datetime features using the below function,

```
def get_date_features(data):
    # generate date features
    data['year'] = data['date'].dt.year
    data['quarter'] = data['date'].dt.quarter
    data['month'] = data['date'].dt.month
    data['day'] = data['date'].dt.day
    data['weekday'] = data['date'].dt.weekday
    data['is_monthend'] = data['date'].dt.is_month_end * 1
    data['is_monthstart'] = data['date'].dt.is_month_start * 1
    data['is_quarterend'] = data['date'].dt.is_quarter_end * 1
    data['is_quarterstart'] = data['date'].dt.is_quarter_start * 1
    data['is_yearend'] = data['date'].dt.is_year_end * 1
    data['is_yearstart'] = data['date'].dt.is_year_start * 1
    data['dayofyear'] = data['date'].dt.dayofyear
    data['weekofyear'] = data['date'].dt.weekofyear
    data['daysinmonth'] = data['date'].dt.days_in_month

    return data

data = get_date_features(data)
```

and then changing the datatypes

```
cols = ['quarter', 'month', 'day','weekofyear', 'daysinmonth',
       'weekday', 'is_monthend', 'is_monthstart', 'is_quarterend',
       'is_quarterstart', 'is_yearend', 'is_yearstart', 'dayofyear'
       ]

for col in cols:
    data[col] = data[col].astype(np.uint8)

for col in ['year']:
    data[col] = data[col].astype(np.uint16)
```

When I check for dtypes, `print(data.dtypes)`, I can see them converted,

```
year                       uint16
quarter                     uint8
month                       uint8
day                         uint8
weekday                     uint8
is_monthend                 uint8
is_monthstart               uint8
is_quarterend               uint8
is_quarterstart             uint8
is_yearend                  uint8
is_yearstart                uint8
dayofyear                   uint8
weekofyear                  uint8
daysinmonth                 uint8
```

When I run `data.visualize()` to see the parallelize plan for the dask computation the code is running for more than an hour and I have aborted it.
And I tried running `data=data.compute()`, which aborts due to insufficient memory error.

> I am using 16GB RAM.
>   ~2GB of RAM is occupied before `data.compute()` step

while executing `data.head()`, I am able to see the top 5 rows with the datetime extracted features, but `data.shape.compute()` returns an error, `'tuple' object has no attribute 'compute'`

Is there a need to run `data.compute()` here. 
Also, when I try to `merge` another dataframe after this process (or) try to generate **lag & groupby** features, execution is aborted with **insufficient memory error**.

Is **dask** right tool for my problem or is there any other python package that may help me solve this problem?

Also, is there any way to solve this without increasing RAM configuration?
Any help/direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `.visualize` method uses the graphviz library for visualization.  That library is slow and doesn't work well beyond a few hundred tasks.

Calling `.compute` on your dataframe will return the entire result in memory as a single pandas dataframe.  If your data is too large then this will fill up your memory.  Perhaps you want to store the result to disk instead with a method like `to_csv` or `to_parquet`?

Comment: After storing the result to the disk, I should again read the file since I have to merge this data with another file/dataframe and I should also create some more grouped(using groupby) features. This I am unable to achieve currently, when I try to merge & create groupby features, the execution aborts due to insufficient memory.